# jquery validator depends rule if value not equal and radio is selected

Tags: jquery, validation

I have run into a slight wall when it comes to adding a secondary condition to a depends rule in my validation. If a user has not logged in and the field value is blank, then the rule needs to validate. Alternatively, if a user has logged in and the field is populated with a masked entry containing "***" then the validation needs to be disabled on that field. The dependancy i presently have in place does not seem to be affective under these conditions.

```
$form.validate({
   rules: {
     cardNumber: {
            digits: true,
            inputFormat: true,
            required: {
                depends: function(element) {
                    if ($("#radioButton").is(":checked")) {
                        if ($('input[name="accnum"]').val().indexOf('*') == 0){
                            return false;
                        } else {
                            return true;
                        }
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }


                }
            }
        }
        }
    });
}
```

I just need to understand how to setup this dual dependancy. Do I need to add a method instead?

Comment: how many radios do you have more than one????

Comment: they are dynamic, so > 1

Answer (score 0):

You can use `&&` operator for that:

```
if ($("#radioButton").is(":checked") && ($('input[name="accnum"]').val().indexOf('*') == 0)) {
  return false;
} else {
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it appears the digits rule needed to be dependant too.

```
       cardNumber: {
            digits : {
                depends: function(element) {
                    return $('input[name="accNum"]').val().indexOf('*') != 0;
                }
            },
            inputFormat: true,
            required: {
                depends: function(element) {
                    return $("#radioButton").is(":checked");
                }
            }
        },
```